# RNN_LSTM_TENSORFLOW does not feed updated w, b in new epoch, although it does in the next batch in the same epoch

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a problem, it may be obvious but I don't know how to fix it.
Although it seems that the w, b are updated in each batch, when a new epoch beggins the w, b are not the last ones(the ones that come from the last batch). Thus, the nn does the same thing in each epoch without getting better.

Here is the code, if you see something please tell me!

if **name** == '**main**':

```
tf.reset_default_graph() #sos τελειο

# Training Parameters
lr = 0.0001
epochs = 10
batch_size = 100
total_series_length = 10000
training_steps = int(total_series_length / batch_size) #ποσες φορες θα αλλαξουν τα w, b 
display_step = int(training_steps / 4) 

# Network Parameters
timesteps = 1 
look_back_window = 80 # num of inputs
num_hidden = 200 # num of features/nodes at hidden layer 
num_output = 1 

# inputs
a, b, steps = (1, 10*np.pi, total_series_length - 1)
step = (b - a)/steps
x = np.array( [ a + i*step for i in range(steps + 1) ], dtype = np.float32 )
sequence = np.sin(x)
traindata =  sequence[ : len(sequence) ] #διαλεγω τι ποσοστο θα κανω train
print('traindata.shape = {}'.format(traindata.shape))
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(traindata, look_back_window)
print('trainX.shape = {}, trainX.shape = {}'.format(trainX.shape, trainY.shape))

# Graph input
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, timesteps, look_back_window])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])#, num_output])

# Define weights
w = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden, num_output]), dtype = tf.float32)}
b = {'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_output]), dtype = tf.float32)}

last_output = RNN(X, w, b,look_back_window, num_hidden)
prediction_operation = tf.nn.tanh(last_output) #sigmoid maybe better, check

# Define loss and optimizer
loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = last_output, labels = Y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
train_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)

# Initialize the variables (i.e. assign their default value)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the initializers
    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(epochs) :
        print('\n epoch = {}'.format(epoch))
        for step in range(0, training_steps): #παει απο το 0 εως το 99 step = 100steps
            batch_x, batch_y = trainX[ (step * batch_size) : (batch_size + step * batch_size), : ], trainY[ (step * batch_size) : (batch_size + step * batch_size) ]
            batch_x = batch_x.reshape(batch_x.shape[0], timesteps, batch_x.shape[1])

            sess.run(train_operation, feed_dict = {X : batch_x, Y : batch_y})
            loss = sess.run(loss_operation, feed_dict={X : batch_x, Y : batch_y})
            pred_batch = sess.run(prediction_operation, feed_dict = {X : batch_x})

            if  (step % display_step == 0 or step == training_steps - 1 ):
                # Calculate batch loss
                print( '{} training step'.format(step) )
                #print( 'batch_x.shape = {}, batch_y.shape = {}'.format(batch_x.shape, batch_y.shape) )
                print( 'loss = {}'.format(loss) )
```

Comment: ok problem solved. In this type of problem loss function softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is not suitable(it would be if it was a cllassification problem). I used RMSE.